# Constructing a subsequence

Tags: real-analysis

An unbounded sequence has a monotonic unbounded subsequence. This seems obvious, but I can't think of how to prove it. My attempt:

Let $(x_n)$ be an unbounded sequence. Let $S_n= \{  |x_1|, |x_2|. |x_3|, ..., |x_n|\}$, and let $(X_n)= \{x_n:|x_n|= sup\ S_n\}$. Then $(X_n)$ is unbounded, since any bound on $(X_n)$ would be a bound on $(x_n)$. And since $sup \ S_n \in S_{n+1}$ for all $n$, we have $X_n \le X_{n+1}$ for all $n$. Therefore $(X_n)$ is an unbounded, monotonic subsequence of $(x_n)$.

But then I realize that $(X_n)$ needn't be monotonic. Consider the sequence $y_n = {n(-1^{n})}$. Here $(x_n)$ and $(X_n)$ are the same sequence, and $(x_n)$ clearly isn't monotonic.

So, my question is, if we know that a sequence is unbounded, but we don't know if the sequence is bounded above, below, or both, can we construct an unbounded monotonic subsequence? It seems like the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded, the sequence $\{|x_n|\}$ is unbounded above. Let $n_1 = 1$ and for each $k \ge 2$ select $n_k$ with the property that $|x_{n_{k}}| \ge |x_{n_{k-1}}| + 1$. Then $\{|x_{n_k}|\}$ increases to $\infty$. Now look at the subsequence of positive terms of $\{x_{n_k}\}$ and the subsequence of negative terms. Both are monotone, and at least one of these is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is an algorithmic one. Your choices of terms in the subsequence are irrevocable. You are fed the terms of your sequence one by one and the only guarantee is that it will be unbounded. Of course, if you knew it's unbounded above you only have to wait for the next term exceeding all previous and also $n$.

I  think there isn't an algorithm in that sense.